# access UIView method from Cocos2D class

Tags: class, uiview, methods, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Cocos2D, and I need to access a parent method in a UIView that is added to a UIViewController from another class.  My hierarchy goes like this:

**Branch 1:** window > viewController.view > glView > joinedMapsScene > joinedMapsLayer

**Branch 2:** window > viewController.view > foregroundLabelView

When my label class used to be part of Cocos2D, accessing was easy by doing something like this:

`JoinedMapsScene *joinedMapsScene = (JoinedMapsScene*)self.parent;
[joinedMapsScene.tetraCounter incTetras:-1];`

But now I need to call the method in foregroundLabelView from joinedMapsLayer. It may not be so much of a cocos2D question, but I'm just really confused about this sort of stuff still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had understood well you want to retrieve the foregroundLabelView instance from  joinedMapsLayer. There is a way but I don't know if it's optimal.
You can in your AppDelegate.h instantiate a foregroundLabelView.

Then when you init your foregroundLabelView you assign it to the AppDelegate foregroundLabelView: in your foregroundLabelView.m (you have to import AppDelegate.h), at the end of the init method you can do

```
AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.foregroundLabelView = self;
```

Then whenever you want you can retrieve it by doing:

```
ForegroundLabelView * tmp = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).foregroundLabelView;
```

and then access the method:

```
[tmp method];
```

I think this should work.

Comment: So this means I no longer can add foregroundLabelView as a subView to viewController.view?

Comment: Nono! You can! But you also assign a pointer to it from app delegate. In this way you can retrieve it from everywhere by calling the pointer to it from the delegate!

Comment: The view is always the same! And it's only One! But you have Two methods to access it: from its class( and child as you said) and also from AppDelegate ( and so from all classes, since you can retrieve appDelegate from all classes).

Comment: This sounds awesome. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: you have to write a property in appDelegate.h for foregroundLabelView. foregroundLabelView should be an accessible instance variable of AppDelegate.h.

Comment: I got it working! Thank you very much. The only issue I had was not making properties for the classes in my delegate, which I should have done in the first place.